# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Stylesheets

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

The project I'm working on allows an end-user to modify CSS code to integrate the application as best possible.  Most of the CSS values are stored in a database and need to be retrieved and parsed dynamically.

I setup a Style controller, and gave each stylesheet an action, and then passed the configuration data through to the View.  I set the ContentType to "text/css" and then generated the stylesheets.

This works fine, but the problem I'm running into is this: none of the code works in the application.  I include it in the head code, but it doesn't parse in the code.

An example of what I do is this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" ContentType="text/css" %>

.element {
    background-color: <%= ViewData.Model.BackgroundColor %>;
}
```

I include it like so:

```
<link href="/style/Basic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

When I include the CSS code in a partial view and include it using the ViewModel (wrapped in style tags) in an action, then everything works fine.  It is when I try to parse this as a separate file when it does not work.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly?  Or is there some kind of glitch?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What output do you get when you point your browser at `/style/Basic`?  You might also check the HTTP headers returned to ensure that they look ok.

Comment: I have tried with similar code to yours,   and it works when I use those two snippets.   I would check firebug or fiddler first to see if the request goes through.  Either that or I am misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool such as HTTPWatch to verify that the stylesheet is being sent down and not 404'd

Comment: When I access the stylesheet, it looks fine.  That is what's confusing me.

Comment: I retract that comment.  Turns out that I forgot to pass an id into the URL, which is required for every controller =\ .

I feel like an idiot now xD .

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Basic()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        var basicVM = new BasicVM()
                          {
                              BackgroundColor = "Lime",

                          };
        return View(basicVM);

    }
```

And the View

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication3.Controllers.BasicVM>"       ContentType="text/css" %>
    body {
      background-color: <%= ViewData.Model.BackgroundColor %>;
        }
```

and the test page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
     <title>Test</title>
     <link href="/Home/Basic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
 </head>
 <body>
     <div>
      Test
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Turns everything Green